# Why simple Jersey hello-world application take 3.5 seconds to startup in Tomcat?

Tags: java, jersey

I have a very simple hello-world servlet which just respond "HelloWorld". Re-deploy to Tomcat take only 750ms.

When I try to use very simple Jersey hello-world application, then re-deploy to Tomcat will take 3400ms. It contains only 1 Controller with one method responding "HelloWorld" and nothing more.

[Official Jersey example application](https://maven.java.net/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=releases&g=com.sun.jersey.samples&a=helloworld-webapp&v=1.19.1&c=project&e=zip)

How is it possible that it takes so long even when this application is so small? And how can I tune this startup time to take less than 1000ms?

Comment: Share your code please.

Comment: Well i was trying but I can't post here web.xml anyway because then formatting goes wild. So I have posted here link to that original app which is completely same as mine.

Comment: Goodness, use copy-paste and then the `{}` in the menu and take the website tour!

Comment: No the {} not work for multiline xml file. Nevertheless, are you surprised it's slow? I'm not, Spring Boot is starting 5 seconds in basic config with Jersey.

Comment: I suggest u analysing tomcat class loader. Which jersey libs r u using?  When tomcat loads jersey classes, it can be take some time.